# How to make more than 1 socket to the same host and port?

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

I am trying to forward multiple sockets communication to a target socket. So I need to make multiple connection to that target socket, but when I try to connect to it for the second time, I get this:

```
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I think the problem is with the other end of the socket, i.e port and host and because there is already a connection between port related to my program and target port, to have a second connection I need a second port for my program.
I hope my problem be clear for you guys.
Any Idea how to do it?

This is a test program just to show the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

class Sample
{
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static void Main()
    {
        Socket[] s = new Socket[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint localEndp = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1100);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            s[i] = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            connectDone.Reset();
            s[i].BeginConnect(localEndp,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), s[i]);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
            s[i].Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(i.ToString() + ": hi.\r\n"));
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    }
}
```

---

I even tried to bind my sockets to different ports, but still second socket gets that exception.

Comment: you'll need to post code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @xaxxon But is it possible to have more than one socket to same port?

Comment: @pranitkothari It should be possible. Web browsers usually do that. they can connect to same port of same host from different sockets.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one socket to same port? Well depends on the server, there are server which does not permit multiple concurrent connections from the same IP. You could try to `telnet 127.0.0.1 1100` from several cmd consoles and see how many you can connect.

Comment: Is the server also from you / your company or is it a third party system where you can't do any changes on the code?

Comment: You cannot bind more than one socket to a single tcp or udp socket.  You can have multiple sockets accepted from that one, though.

Comment: @SAM I think xaxxon may be right. But still I curious to know answer to your question. Kindly post answer yourself if you got it.

Comment: @RolandBär Yes it is. I've used netcat for listening to a port and the problem occurred. I found that ja_mesa is right, it depends on the process listening to port. netcat just accepts one socket. The problem doesn't belong to c# or OS.

Comment: @pranitkothari I refer you to ja_mesa comments too. That is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that there is no open port on that IP. The IP is valid but the remote host replied that it will not accept a connection on this port.

You should be getting this error even for the very first connection.

Find out why the port is not open.

Btw, you use of async connect is counter-productive. You have non of the async benefits and all of the disadvantages. But this is not the point of this question.

Comment: No, the port is not closed, but just accepts 1 connection. (i.e, it's not accepting incoming connections inside a loop)

Comment: @SAM you can have multiple incoming connections on the same port. How could a web-server possibly serve multiple clients if that wasn't the case? Btw, if you think the server is at fault, why are we discussing the client in this question? The client is ok, there's just noone listening. Try `telnet 127.0.0.1 1100`. It will give you the same error.

Comment: Yes you are right and if you read comments below question, you see that I have told which one is the answer to my question.

Comment: I did not see that this is an old question. Stack Overflow sometimes seems to bump obsolete questions. Anyway, if this is the answer, accept it and the question is done.